# Decode base64 and unzip vector in-memory

Tags: r, vector, base64, unzip

I'm using RCurl to GET a vector of zipped and base64 encoded text data.
I need to decode it and unzip it to get the original content. 
I figured that I can use ***base64decode*** from ***caTools*** package to decode the vector.
Is there a way I can unzip the vector in memory? I've found unzip packages for R that work with .zip files. I'm trying not to write the content to a file, unzip and read them back. Is there a way I can decode and unzip in memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `memDecompress` in `base` R, but you're [looking at support](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/memCompress.html) for `gzip`, `bzip2` & `xz`. If you – at the OS layer – create a RAM disk, you're *technically* not really writing to a permanent file and getting similar in-memory benefits (if you can't use `memDecompress`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This is what I was looking for but memDecompress is failing in my case. Probably because the vector I have a raw format of a zip file containing a file. The below code works for me. I need to write the zip file and read one file inside it.

`stream <- base64decode(encoded, what="raw");
to.write <- file("decoded.zip", "wb");
writeBin(stream, to.write);
close(to.write);
content <- read.table(unz("decode.zip", "Object.bin"));`

It looks like memDecompress is designed decompress string and not to read from a zipfile. Any suggestions for this??

Comment: btw, I found package `Rcompression` from http://www.omegahat.org/ that looks promising but I'm trying to limit myself to CRAN. I don't own the setup we are working on. For the same reason we can't create a RAM drive too.